# How to include all points in the HERE routing response?

Tags: here-api, points

Question on HERE. Com. There is a function to which I give two points: the FROM point and the point TO. Does the function give me all the points on the route?

I use API: `https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=&app_code=&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled`

But this API give me only instruction points. I want take all route point on this way. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please attach sample code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I use API: 
`https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json
?app_id=&app_code=
&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4
&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled`
But this API give me only instruction points. I want take all route point on this way. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive all route points, you should include `representation=display` parameter.

See [HERE routing API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) documentation for more details.